# Authorize attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Need help on this authorize code to define a specific sub group in my controller.

[Authorize(Roles = "RABEE\domain user accounts\zam gas industry\california\domain local groups\ZamReader")]

RABEE is the domain name that is why I have \ 
Group Name i have added users is: ZamReader

what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Active Ditrectory? If so, make sure that your using a "Security Group" not a "Distribution Group".